# Switching project from JDK 1.7 to 1.6 BufferedReader

Tags: java, transfer

I had to switch my school project JDK 1.7 to 1.6. I created a new project on platform 1.6 and copied all packed in my project and seems like 1.6 doesn't support this kind of buffered reader, any help please? I need to read from a file in src. if I use Scanner should I be fine?

```
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(sDataPath))){

Error " Resource specification not allowed here for source level below 1.7"
```

Comment: Are you using in jsp?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not a matter of `BufferedReader` being a problem - it's your [try-with-resources statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html), which was introduced in Java 7. You'll need to close the reader manually:

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(sDataPath));
try {
    ...
} finally {
    reader.close();
}
```

As an aside, I'd advise *against* using `FileReader` - use an `InputStreamReader` wrapping a `FileInputStream` so you can specify the encoding.

Oh, and if you're allowed to use external libraries, you may find that [Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com) will make your resource handling simpler :)

Comment: Thank you! we can't use external libraries :/

Answer (score 3):

Java 7 allows automatic disposal of resources using that `try()` construct. Java 6 doesn't have it. You need to write something like:

```
BufferedReader br=null
try {
    br = new BufferedReader(...); // create and use BufferedReader here
}
finally {
    if(br!=null) br.close();
}
```